# Project is not running with visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Everything was working fine, i.e all my C# codes and projects were executing fine. But now when executing any project by clicking on the green icon/F5, it shows loading mouse symbol. And cant run the project. Can build and rebuild the solution. And also can run the project with "Browse with" option. I have tried by deleting '.vs' folder. But have no effect.

[image]

Comment: When you choose `Browse With…`, is your project runnable for all the listed Browsers? If you choose another browser and set it as default, then press F5 will your project start running?

Comment: When you choose Browse With…, is your project runnable for all the listed Browsers?  - Yes.   If you choose another browser and set it as default, then press F5 will your project start running? - No still not working.

Comment: I have updated the windows version. It is working now. ,

Comment: Ok, great, happy to hear that.